# Does Brzozowsky's algorithm always produce the right minimum DFA?

Tags: algorithms, finite-automata

Let's say I have this NFA automaton **A**:

```
[q1] [reject]
    [q1] 0 -> [q2]
[q2] [reject]
    [q2] 1 -> [q3]
[q3] [accept]
[q0] [reject][initial]
    [q0] 1 -> [q1]
    [q0] 0 -> [q0]
    [q0] 1 -> [q0]
```

The output of Brzozowsky's minimization method, executed manually using JFLAP and confirmed by my own implementation is:

```
[q1] [reject]
    [q1] 1 -> [q2]
    [q1] 0 -> [q1]
[q2] [reject]
    [q2] 1 -> [q2]
    [q2] 0 -> [q3]
[q3] [reject]
    [q3] 0 -> [q1]
    [q3] 1 -> [q4]
[q4] [accept]
    [q4] 0 -> [q3]
    [q4] 1 -> [q2]
[q0] [reject][initial]
    [q0] 1 -> [q2]
    [q0] 0 -> [q1]
```

To be specific, this is the output of `det(rev(det(rev(det(A))))` , since A is an NFA, where `det()` is the determinize function and `rev()` is the reverse one.
But this is not the minimum DFA, the right one obtained by Hopcroft's algorithm after the determinization of **A** is:

```
[q1] [reject]
    [q1] 1 -> [q1]
    [q1] 0 -> [q2]
[q2] [reject]
    [q2] 0 -> [q0]
    [q2] 1 -> [q3]
[q3] [accept]
    [q3] 1 -> [q1]
    [q3] 0 -> [q2]
[q0] [reject][initial]
    [q0] 1 -> [q1]
    [q0] 0 -> [q0]
```

So I'm pretty confused here.. Why Brzozowsky's method produced the wrong output?

Comment: Brzozowski's algorithm works for DFAs. Perhaps it just doesn't work for NFAs.

Comment: Even if we determinize them in first place?

Comment: In that case it definitely works, but that's not what you did.

Comment: Yes, I did:
det(rev(det(rev( **det(A)** )))

Comment: Try again. Brzozowski works fine. I just did it by hand.

Comment: Just went through it myself; none of the automata had more than 4 productive states (there is a sink state after the second determinization). rev(det(rev(det(A)))) is actually isomorphic to A, and the final result therefore to det(A). Maybe your intermediate results can help tracking down your error?